# Solving a parsing conflict in SQLite grammar

Tags: parser-generator, shift-reduce-conflict, lemon, shift-reduce

I'm trying to extent the SQL language of SQLite at one point (file parse.y). I have a parsing conflict, however the lemon parser does not show anything besides a random "1 parsing conflicts." error message.

The problem is located where create_table can be reduced to both "CREATE" or "CREATE OR REPLACE" which is followed by temp which can also be reduced to an empty token.

```
cmd ::= create_table create_table_args table_properties_args.
create_table ::= createorreplace(C) temp(T) TABLE ifnotexists(E) nm(X) dbnm(Y). {
  // ...
}

%type createorreplace {int}
createorreplace(A) ::= CREATE.  {disableLookaside(pParse); A = 0;}
createorreplace(A) ::= CREATE OR REPLACE.  {disableLookaside(pParse); A = 1;}

%type temp {int}
temp(A) ::= TEMP.  {A = pParse->db->init.busy==0;}
temp(A) ::= .      {A = 0;}
```

How can I make "OR REPLACE" reduced optionally, while preserving that it may be followed by TEMP?

Comment: `OR REPLACE` is not the problem. Why do you think it is? You say that lemon didn't give you any information; what evidence did you collect?

Comment: I did not say this is the problem. The problem is more likely that these are two non-terminals which both be reduced to two alternatives. Though, why that is the case and how to resolve it eludes me.

Comment: The evidence I collected is that removing either temp, or removing reduction of create to OR REPLACE gets parsed correctly.

Comment: Since `temp` is followed by the terminal `TABLE`, it's completely deterministic. That assumes that there is no other production involving those non-terminals; since there is a conflict, I guess that's not the case. It's notoriously difficult to diagnose parsing conflicts when only a little bit of the grammar is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can only guess how and where you might have changed SQLite's SQL grammar, this answer is necessarily somewhat tentative. But it might be useful anyway.

The original SQL grammar contains the following productions (I left out the actions since they are never relevant in diagnosing conflicts):

```
cmd          ::= create_table create_table_args.
create_table ::= createkw temp(T) TABLE
                 ifnotexists(E) nm(Y) dbnm(Z).
createkw(A)  ::= CREATE(A).
temp(A)      ::= TEMP.
temp(A)      ::= .
cmd          ::= createkw(X) temp(T) VIEW
                 ifnotexists(E) nm(Y) dbnm(Z) eidlist_opt(C) AS select(S).
```

You seem to have modified `create_table` to instead read:

```
create_table ::= createorreplace(C) temp(T) TABLE
                 ifnotexists(E) nm(X) dbnm(Y).
createorreplace(A) ::= CREATE.
createorreplace(A) ::= CREATE OR REPLACE.
```

That change indeed creates a conflict, but it has nothing to do with `temp` being nullable. In fact, it has very little to do with the non-terminal `temp` at all. You could replace `temp` with `TEMP` (thereby making it obligatory rather than optional) and you would still have a shift-reduce conflict.

The conflict occurs for inputs which start `CREATE TEMP`. That input could be the start of

- `CREATE TEMP TABLE ...`
- `CREATE TEMP VIEW ...`
  Those are obviously different syntaxes, and there is no ambiguity

But when the terminal `CREATE` has just been read and the terminal `TEMP` is the lookahead token, both of those possibilities are still available. That's not necessarily a problem; a bottom-up parser does not need to resolve which possible production will be used until it gets to the end of the production. So the original grammar works fine, without conflicts.

But note that the original grammar does not have a `cmd` production which starts with the terminal `CREATE`. What it has are several `cmd` productions which start with the non-terminal `createkw`. But there is no possibility of confusion there, either. The terminal `CREATE` is reduced to `createkw` in both `cmd` productions (and other `cmd` productions I didn't list, which also start with `createkw`).

However, in your modified grammar, the two productions do not both start with `createkw`. One of them was changed to start with `createorreplace`.

Inputs which do not include the optional keyword `TEMP` still parse without any problem. If `TEMP` is not present, the lookahead token will be `TABLE` in the `create_table` command, and the lookahead token will be `VIEW` in the create view command. Since the lookahead tokens differ, the parser has no trouble deciding whether to reduce to `createkw` or to reduce to `createorreplace`. Similarly, if the input were actually `CREATE OR REPLACE ...`, the lookahead token would be `OR`, which unambiguously forces a reduction to `createorreplace`.

But the problematic input, as shown above, starts `CREATE TEMP`. Now, the parser must decide, without seeing anything which follows the terminal `TEMP`, whether to reduce `CREATE` to `createkw` or to reduce it to `createorreplace`. Since that determination cannot be made, a conflict is reported. (And you'll find a lot more information about that conflict by looking through the Lemon report file, `parse.out`.)

The solution (if my guess about your grammar modifications was correct) is to avoid forcing the parser to make an unnecessary decision. That requires a little bit of grammar duplication:

```
cmd          ::= create_table create_table_args.
create_table ::= createkw temp(T) TABLE ifnotexists(E) nm(Y) dbnm(Z).
create_table ::= createorreplace temp(T) TABLE ifnotexists(E) nm(Y) dbnm(Z).
createkw(A)  ::= CREATE(A).
createorreplace(A) ::= CREATE OR REPLACE.
temp(A)      ::= TEMP.
temp(A)      ::= .
cmd          ::= createkw(X) temp(T) VIEW ifnotexists(E) nm(Y) dbnm(Z)
                 eidlist_opt(C) AS select(S).
```

Now, the terminal `CREATE` not followed by `OR REPLACE` is always reduced to `createkw`, while the sequence `CREATE OR REPLACE` is always reduced to `createorreplace`. This works because there is no possible parse for a `cmd` starting `CREATE OR`, other than `CREATE OR REPLACE`.